# How to fetch results from multiple partitions in DynamoDb in a single QueryResultPage

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to query dynamodb where my actual data is partitioned in 3 parts ( based on the hash function). I would like to fetch results from all the partitions for a matching primary key and then paginate through them. I am not sure if it is possible.

I know how to fetch records from a single partition. I use below code for doing this and it retrieves the data from that partition only but not from other partitions even though those partitions may have the same keys

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
        eav.put(":partitionKey", new AttributeValue().withS(hashKey));
DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyClazz> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyClazz>()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("partitionKey = :partitionKey")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav)
                .withLimit(limit)
                .withExclusiveStartKey(lastEvaluatedKey);
```

But this will fetch the data from first partition. I want to fetch the data from other remaining partitions in a single QueryResultPage so that I can paginate through them.

Is it possible to do that?

What I mean is below condition executed together such that I get a single QueryResultPage

`("key = :partition1 or key = :partition2 or key = :partition3")`

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with DynamoDB, you can't actually have an OR condition on the partition key, but there are a couple of way of solving your issue.

The easiest is to use **TransactGetItems** or **BatchGetItems**, basically you will send several queries togheter, transactions have a limit or 10 per request and batch 25.

I'm not sure which SDK you're using, but it probably has these functions mapped.

Comment: Not sure if BatchgetItems would solve the pagination thing like the dynamodbmapper does with LastEvaluatedKey.

Comment: @creed I think you're confusing things, your client logic already knows all the keys it needs to get, so pagination is implemented by your code.